# Can't create any class on Salesforce Production

Tags: unit-test

We are using Eclipse to get the code from production. We tried to create a class but it did not allow to create anything on SF production, just notified " File only saved locally, not to server"
Here is new SF we have just bought, I also tried to do the same on another SF it allowed to create fine. Please help us why we can't create anything on SF Production? or SF prevented it?

Thanks!
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Short story: You can't create Apex classes or Triggers in Production. Have a look at this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005267&language=en_US)

Comment: Strange here, I also tried on another SF, it allowed to create a empty class, changed minor code and same them to server. I am using Enterprise Edition, I am not sure the version is limited.

Comment: I am a system Administrator